# Fantasy film about man & girl bricked up alive and escaping by turning his cloak into a hang glider

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember a film I saw years ago (1980's?).

The only part I clearly remember is a man and girl being bricked up alive (in a tower?) and escaping by turning his (magically large) coat or cloak into a rudimentary hang glider.

The film had a medieval sword/sorcery setting.

Comment: "Years ago" like 2010 or "Years ago" like 1970?

Comment: What about this makes it either science-fiction or fantasy?

Comment: some british POW made a hang glider out of sheets and poridge and to attempt escape from a castle in ww2, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colditz_Cock
im pretty sure this isnt what your looking for, but foreverone else its a cool story :D

Comment: Someone looking for the same film, it looks like; http://www.entropiaplanets.com/threads/wistrels-what-film-was-that-game.11123/

Comment: When rescuing Lazer Lady, CondorMan removed his coat to reveal a hang-glider... but they weren't bricked up.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about sf

Comment: Assuming the link above is the same film, I've added in some more detail

Comment: I've not seen it but I know that Ator the Invincible 2 (aka The Blademaster and Cave Dwellers) is a S&S film where the protagonist uses a hang-glider.

Comment: I've found the film I was looking for. It was a Russian film called 'the story of the Voyages' made in 1983. Thanks for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Peasant girl searches for her kidnapped brother who can sense gold. When she (years later) finds him, he's no longer an innocent](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/197786/peasant-girl-searches-for-her-kidnapped-brother-who-can-sense-gold-when-she-ye)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the film I was looking for. It was a Russian film called *[The Story of the Voyages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Story_of_Voyages)* made in 1983.

[image: Movie poster]

> In a medieval fantasy kingdom, two orphans, May and his sister Martha, live in poverty. A group of robbers kidnap May to use his magic talent: he feels sick when surrounded by gold, therefore he can feel gold from a long distance.
>
> Martha goes on a quest to find her brother. She is soon joined by a travelling scientist, Orlando. Together, the two wander through various fantastic countries. They visit a city built on the back of a dragon, and see it burnt down when the dragon wakes. In another city, they are sentenced to death for starting a bar brawl. They manage to escape from prison using hang-glider Orlando invented. Finally they land in a country hit by Black Death, which is personified as a witch in black. Orlando sacrifices himself to stop the plague.