# Peasant girl searches for her kidnapped brother who can sense gold. When she (years later) finds him, he's no longer an innocent

Tags: story-identification, movie

I've spent quite a few years searching for a film I saw when I was young which for me was in the 80's so the latest this could have been is 1990.

My "memory" of it is very fragmented. I seem to remember it being dubbed into English, no idea what the base language was. There was a poor orphan peasant girl who was searching for her younger brother. He has been kidnapped by a gang of thieves because he had the magical ability to sense and find gold so he was useful to them. The peasant girl journeys, possibly for years, searching and having adventures.

Then towards the end she finally finds her brother who's grown up. Because of his gift he's now the king of the thieves and lives in a big castle. But he's not the innocent little boy she had been searching for and is a mean young man now. I cant remember much more except that as it ends his powers are revealed to have grown to the point that not only can he sense gold but he can now summon it to come to him. I've kind of got this mental image of him yelling

> "come to me gold"

and skeletons being pulled out of the ground because of the gold jewellery they are wearing.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How many years ago would you have seen this?  Was the movie in colour or black&white?  Are there any other details you can think of that might help readers recognize the movie?  Identifiable characteristics of the actors?  You might check out the [guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for other things you might be able to add.

Comment: This is mostly all I can remember. The movie was colour. I was a child so it would be 1990ish or earlier. I dont really remember with any clarity much more than the detail I've given anything more is just guesses and so probably not helpful. The girl hunting for her brother was maybe brunette. The brother was maybe blond?

Comment: I've just asked an identification question about a movie from my childhood that has some similarities to this one. Do you think it could be the same movie? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203236/movie-about-a-girl-looking-for-her-kidnapped-brother

Comment: You're looking for the Russian film *The Story of the Voyages* from 1983. I'd answer it, but it was already answered in [this previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72444/fantasy-film-about-man-girl-bricked-up-alive-and-escaping-by-turning-his-cloak), so perhaps it's best this was marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

This is the russian film [The Story of Voyages](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0141830/) from 1983. From IMDb:

> In a medieval fantasy kingdom, two orphans, May and his sister Martha, live in poverty. A group of robbers kidnap May to use his magic talent: he feels sick when surrounded by gold, therefore he can feel gold from a long distance.

Everything you mentioned happened there, including the skeleton when her brother summons gold. See also [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203236/movie-about-a-girl-looking-for-her-kidnapped-brother) (and its duplicate). Here are some clips from the film with some commentary:

Comment: I hadn't been back and seen someone answered till my email suddenly decided to let me know all the replies it had grouped unseen in one go. But yes, it absolutely is the Story of the Voyages. Thank you so much for this, is driven me nuts for years wondering if it was real or not. Thanks all.

Comment: @Mykey Hi there! It seems you created two accounts; please merge them by following [these instructions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). This way, you'll be able to accept Walt's answer formally :)